# Can one define (appropriately) a Fourier tranform on a Hilbert space?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I wonder if there is any theory or developement on Fourier transforms on geneal Hilbert spaces $H$. I know there are developements in locally compact Hausdorff spaces but $H$ is unfortunately not locally compact if $\dim H = \infty$.

More concretely I wonder, is there a measure $\mu$ on $H$ such that for any operator $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we can give meaning to
$$\widehat{f}(\xi):=\int_{H} f(x)e^{i\langle x,\xi\rangle} \mu(dx)$$
and if so, if one can derive an inversion formula based on a similar expression as above by taking the conjugate exponential.

Does anyone know about this topic or any reference that could help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may be looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure

Comment: One usually defines the Fourier transform for functions on a locally compact (abelian) group, which can form a Hilbert space. An abstract Hilbert space does not need to consist of such functions. That's not to say that what you propose is not possible.

Comment: It won't be a translation invariant measure, which limits any usefulness.